# Manually setting connection strings in ASP.Net Core Dependency Injection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, quartz.net, quartz

Variations of this question have been asked before but I haven't found one matching my situation and I'm at a bit of a loss.

We have a multi tenant solution that relies on some information from the web request to obtain information about the appropriate database to connect to.  This part is fine, we have a class that extracts information from the user claims and fetches the database from an API.

Where it gets messier is when we already have the connection information in hand for one reason or another.  One case is running a Quartz job where we query an API for a list of *all* tenants then loop over the tenants and perform a series of functions.  Another is where we opened webhooks for external applications to call our API and in doing so we are able to deduce the connection string from the body.

However in both cases we're having trouble creating the context with the connection string in hand.

So for example, we have a class that builds the DBContext and contains the following method

```
public async Task<DbContext> BuildContextAsync()
        {
            string instanceName = _httpContext?.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == Domain.CustomClaimTypes.InstanceName).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();

            var setting = await _instanceFetcher.GetInstanceSettingAsync(instanceName);
            return _dbContextBuilder.BuildContext(setting.DatabaseName);
        }
```

Then later on we have a quartz job that has the following `Execute` method

```
  public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {   
            var instances = await _instanceFetcher.GetAllActiveInstancesAsync();

            foreach (var instance in instances)
            {
                var notifications = await _notificationService.GetAllPendingNotifications();
                // ... more logic, do stuff
            }
   }
```

And this is the problem, I have the instance connection details in hand but I cannot seem to get the `_notificationService` to use the Instance details to create a new DBContext.  I've tried a number of strategies that I've omitted in the code above, but mostly they revolve around setting a property in my ContextBuilder and using that to build the DBContext.  It seems however, that injecting the `_notificationService` in the constructor of the job doesn't give me the opportunity to change the connection string since `_notificationService` is already activated.

It would also be very cumbersome to manually instantiate all the dependencies that `_notificationService` and its dependencies need.

I suspect I'm looking at a bit of an overhaul of how I'm creating the DBContext but I'm not sure what the appropriate strategy is to use it in both of my use cases.

Comment: As it turns out, I had my DBContext lifetime set to Transient so I needed to set the connection string each time I created a new service.  I made set the lifetime to Scoped and was able to manually set the connection string which then opened up a number of palatable possibilities for how to handle the problem